# Focus on input field inside bootstrap modal is not happening in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, bootstrap-modal

Test Component

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from 
'@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'app-test',
templateUrl: './test.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
private isFocus: boolean;


constructor() { }
ngOnInit() { }
setFocus(focus) {
this.isFocus = focus;
}
}
```

Test Component HTML

```
<div class="container">
<h2>Modal Example</h2>
<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data- 
target="#myModal"
(click)="setFocus(true)">Open Modal</button>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times; 
 </button>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <my-modal [isFocus]="isFocus"></my-modal>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" 
 (click)="setFocus(false)">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Modal Component

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ElementRef, ViewChild, AfterViewInit, 
Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
import { Console } from '@angular/core/src/console';

@Component({
selector: 'my-modal',
templateUrl: './my-modal.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./my-modal.component.scss']
})
export class MyModalComponent implements OnInit {

@Input() isFocus: boolean = false;
@ViewChild('appFocus') appFocus: ElementRef;
constructor(private renderer2: Renderer2) { }

ngOnInit() {
}

ngOnChanges() {
console.log(this.isFocus);
if (this.isFocus) {
  this.appFocus.nativeElement.focus();
}
}
}
```

Modal Component HTML

```
<div>
<h1>Modal Test</h1>
<input type="text" id="modal_input" #appFocus>
</div>
```

Expected Result: Focusing on input field is not happening. Focusing is happening only once on page load after that it is not happening every-time we open the modal.

Methods tried: used autofocus attribute provided by html 5 but got no result.

Comment: There's way too much code here. Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ngOnChanges isn't in sync with view cycle, for that you would need to call your .focus() function after a callback from ngAfterViewInit or simply wrap `this.appFocus.nativeElement.focus()` with a `setTimeout` like this:

```
setTimeout(() => this.appFocus.nativeElement.focus(), 0);
```